# df.style.apply centers multiindex values in display

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

When I run

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
df = pd.DataFrame('a',index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1]]*3),columns=['A'])
display(df)
display(df.style.apply(lambda x: ['']*len(x),axis=1))
```

in Jupyter, I get the following displays (unfortunately I cannot upload screenshots)

```
0 0 0 a
    1 a
  1 0 a
    1 a
1 0 0 a
    1 a
  1 0 a
    1 a
```

-

```
    0 a
  0  
    1 a
0
    0 a
  1  
    1 a
    0 a
  0  
    1 a
1
    0 a
  1  
    1 a
```

**1: How do I prevent that change?**

**2: Since I actually don't dislike the second format completely: How can I fix the backgrounds in the multiindex, so that the boundaries of the groups in each multiindex level become visually clear?**

(PS: In my actual code, the lambda returns `'background: green'` for some rows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bit of relevant discussion on GitHub [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16792) and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16879) regarding the default `vertical-alignment` CSS attribute that should be applied to `th`'s; I think these CSS styles should give you a good starting point:

```py
s=df.style.set_table_styles([
    {'selector': 'th',
    'props': [
        ('border-style', 'solid'),
        ('border-color', 'Red'),
        ('vertical-align','top')
    ]
    }]
)
HTML(s.render())
```

This would top-align the MultiIndices, and give them a red border.

**Update**

I don't know *how* you're evaluating your style/conditions, but if you had some 'b's in your DF (e.g. `df.loc[0,0,1]='b'`, `df.loc[1,0,1]='b'`) then you could define a styling function like:

```py
def color_b_green(value):
  if value == 'b':
    color = 'blue'
  else:
    color = 'black'
  return 'color: %s' % color
```

and finally chain everything together (cleaned up here) like:

```py
styles=[
    {'selector': 'th',
    'props': [
        ('border-style', 'solid'),
        ('border-color', 'Red'),
        ('vertical-align','top')
    ]
    }]

(df.style
    .apply(lambda x: ['']*len(x),axis=1)
    .applymap(color_b_green)
    .set_table_styles(styles))
```

Comment: How do I combine this with the kind of style changes I make with style.apply? I cant just chain it because `Styler object has no attribute style`

Comment: @Bananach I've updated my answer to show how to chain styles; I don't know how you're applying things right now, but I guess it's the cleanest way to style using functions (hence the additional `.applymap()`).