# Have the same index for multiple rows in dataframe, shown verticaly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe that looks similar to an excel file, something like this:

[image]

The code I am using right now:

## 1) Import packages

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
    
    
# 2) Define functions

def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')
    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)
    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

    for k, cell in mpl_table._cells.items():
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])
    return ax.get_figure(), ax

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Planet'] = ['Earth','Mercury', 'Jupiter']
df['time'] = [2200, 2100, 1500]
df['distance'] = [8, 7.5, 8.2]
df['Bz'] = [9,8, 10]


fig,ax = render_mpl_table(df, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0)
```

What I am getting:

[image]

What I want to do is have the dataframe show the index vertically, using the same index for 3 consequent rows at a time.

Comment: May be you want to take a look at multiindexing?

Comment: Where does your function `render_mpl_table` come from? Did you copy your this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726663/how-to-save-the-pandas-dataframe-series-data-as-a-figure)? Which library are you using to plot? Please add all this information to your question.

Comment: @mosc9575 Yes I did! I am sorry  have included the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? I added column `R(km)`as the expected output you showed but you can
apply the same principle for other column as the second index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Planet'] = ['Earth']*3 + ['Mercury']*3 +['Jupiter']*3
df['R(km)'] = [100]*3 + [200]*3 +[300]*3
df['time'] = [2200, 2100, 1500]*3
df['distance'] = [8, 7.5, 8.2]*3
df['Bz'] = [9,8, 10]*3
df.set_index(['Planet', 'R(km)'])
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks! That's what I was looking for! Do you also happen to know how can I force the index be shown vertically?

Comment: It does not seem to work along with the function though..

Comment: Would it possible to approach differently your rending function, e.i., via modifying the styling of pandas dataframe, e.g. `df.style.set_table_styles`. I did not try but I guess this discussion might be helpful for you in that purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55724702/df-style-apply-centers-multiindex-values-in-display. kr.

Comment: does not seem to help :(